# Computing empirical markov transition probabilities in Julia Data Frames

Tags: dataframe, julia

I want to use Julia DataFrames to construct a 3x3 Markov transition matrix i.e. a frequency matrix that tells me the likelihood of transitioning from each of 3 states to the others. I am trying to learn data frames and I would like to learn the best way to do this. This is more for general learning than about this particular example.

Here's some code I tried so far with some example data but I am not really familiar enough with how to think about dataframes to know how to proceed.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

```
state=[2,2,3,1,1,3,3,2,1,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,1]
statelag=[1,2,2,3,1,1,3,3,2,1,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,3]
df = DataFrame(state=state, statelag=statelag)

markov = combine(groupby(df, [:statelag, :state]), nrow => :cat_countmar)
sort!(markov, :statelag, :state) # this gives the number of occurences of each tranistion

total = combine(groupby(df, :statelag), nrow => :cat_count) 
# this gives the number of occurences of each state


trans = Array{Float64}(undef, (3,3))
# trans should give probability of transitioning between different states
```

I need to basically "divide" `catcountmar` of by `cat_count` so that I'm dividing the number of occurrences of a transition from state i to state j by the number of occurences of state i. This will give the desired transition frequency. But I don't see how to put `markov` and `total` together in one data frame and easily carry out this computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [transform](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/man/split_apply_combine/) function to get results of the same length of your original dataframe. See the code below for an example.

```
state=[2,2,3,1,1,3,3,2,1,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,3,1]
statelag=[1,2,2,3,1,1,3,3,2,1,1,3,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,3,3]
df = DataFrame(state=state, statelag=statelag)

df = transform(groupby(df, [:statelag, :state]), nrow => :cat_countmar)
# get the number of occurrences for each transition

df = transform(groupby(df, :statelag), nrow => :cat_count) 
# get the number of occurrences for each state

df[:,:prob] = df[:,:cat_countmar]./df[:,:cat_count]
# get the transition probability 

trans = unique(df[:,[:statelag,:state,:prob]])
# remove unnecessary rows and columns  

reshape_trans = unstack(trans,:state,:prob)
# Transform into a matrix format

trans_mat = convert(Matrix{Float64},reshape_trans[:,2:4])
# Finally, convert the dataframe to a matrix
```

Final Output:

```
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.285714  0.428571  0.285714
 0.166667  0.166667  0.666667
 0.5       0.25      0.25
```

Comment: I'm not super clear on what exactly the `unstack` function is doing here. If you could elaborate on that, that would be really helpful. I had a look at the docs for that function and was still confused, but if you insist on rtfm I'll give it another shot :) thanks

Comment: The `unstack` is equivalent to `reshape` in other statistical softwares (like stata). It transfers a long panel to a wider (but shorter) panel. You do not necessarily need to do the last two steps as the `trans` dataframe should give all the information you need.